# StringBuilder vs string constructor - the character

Tags: c#, .net

I just saw a code like

```
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            result.Append("?");
        }
        return result.ToString();
```

I know that concatenating with StringBuilder is considered faster (and does not create new instance of a string on every append).  But is there any reason we would not prefer to write

```
return new string('?', n)
```

instead?

Comment: You might be interested in the [Submit to Daily WTF Visual Studio extension](http://inedo.com/downloads/submit-to-wtf)

Answer (score 7):

> But is there any reason we would not prefer to write `return new string("?", n)` instead

The only reason I can think of is unfamiliarity of the developer with the existence of [this string constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsa4321w.aspx). But for people familiar with it, no, there is no reason to not use it.

Also you probably meant:

```
return new string('?', n)
```

Comment: And if you want a mutable string after that, just do `new StringBuilder( new string('?', n))`.

Comment: @leppie for that (unlikely) scenario, `new StringBuilder(n).Append('?',n)` would be better, no?

Comment: Exactly because of unfamiliarity. I got to know this constructor when I was typing something like `new string(Enumerable.Repeat('a', count)...`

Comment: @MarcGravell: Not 'really' unlikely, but +1 for `Append(char, int)`, never knew that one existed!

Comment: @MarcGravell: Not better, your suggestion is about 50% slower than mine  :)  1640ms (yours) vs 1102ms (mine). I suspect `new string(c,n)` simply does a `memset`.

Comment: Man, this is what I like about this forum.  Even asking seemingly yes/no questions you still can learn something new.

Answer (score 4):

The main reason not to use `new string("?", n)` is that no such constructor exists and it won't compile. However, there is absolutely no reason not to use `new string('?', n)`, and I fully encourage you to do so.

Comment: Why the downvote? it is entirely accurate (please also look at the question before edited by another user)